# How to plot step graph in C code

Tags: c, graph, plot

I want to plot an output voltage of a multilevel converter, basically the output should look like [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=multilevel+waveform&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB&rlz=1I7IRFG_enGB523&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mCuJVb6yBYjaU62jn5AD&ved=0CCEQsAQ&biw=1412&bih=724#imgrc=ldaAZ-mgFRLoAM%253A%3BDYNwwJb7cj-YhM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ijser.org%252Fpaper%252FTHD-Minimization-in-Single-Phase-Symmetrical-Cascaded-Multilevel-Inverter-Using-Programmed-PWM-Technique%252FImage_004.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ijser.org%252Fpaper%252FTHD-Minimization-in-Single-Phase-Symmetrical-Cascaded-Multilevel-Inverter-Using-Programmed-PWM-Technique.html%3B317%3B249).

where in each time step, the output voltage increases by ONE step. For example, when t=0s, the v_total is zero, when it comes to t1, the v_total is V, when t=t2(next time step), the v_total is 2V, ...3V...etc

I am coding in C language using Altera Monitor Program for Nios II system.

I have three capacitors which add up ONE capacitor voltage at a time.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    v_total=v_total+v_capacitor[i];
}
```

[image]
There are four plots in the image, please look at the red plot. I draw a green circle in the image, you can see that the value increased from zero to the peak in a slope, but what I expect to see is as drawn in the purple line on the same image.

EDIT: My question is, what technically went wrong in my code that results in the red line plotted instead of the purple line? Or could it be just sampling issue?

Appreciate any input....thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you use GNUPlot?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I send the v_total value to serial plot and real time plot the graph in Matlab. I use C code to program the processor in Altera development board.